# What time servet initialize?

Tags: servlets, initialization, web.xml

I have a doubt about loadonstartup value. I check it within the stackverflow previous answers also.
but some are said load on startup value zero mean initialize the servlet when deploy the application. but some are said zero mean it doesnt load when the first request received. then what is  the corect answer ?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```